# Unfortunately, the app has stopped Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am pretty sure there is no problem in my XML or manifest. The problem has to be in my code (because I had altered my code slightly and it stopped working). The app crashes before it even begins. The error I got is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.trainer.braintrainer/com.trainer.braintrainer.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on
>   a null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   com.trainer.braintrainer.MainActivity.generateQuestion(MainActivity.java:60)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.trainer.braintrainer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:101)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  06-16
>   08:01:16.547 24091-24091/com.trainer.braintrainer I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 24091 SIG: 9

Below is my Main java code:

```
package com.trainer.braintrainer;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Integer> answers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    int locationOfCorrectAnswer;
    Button startButton;
    Button button0;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    int score=0;
    int numberOfQuestions=0;
    TextView answerMessage;
    String message;
    TextView scoreText;
    TextView sumTextView;
    TextView timerText;

    public void generateQuestion(){

        int a=rand.nextInt(21);
        int b=rand.nextInt(21);

        sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(a) + " + " + Integer.toString(b));

        locationOfCorrectAnswer=rand.nextInt(4);
        answers.clear();
        int inCorrectAns;
        for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
            if (i==locationOfCorrectAnswer){
                answers.add(a+b);
            }else{
                inCorrectAns=rand.nextInt(50);
                while (inCorrectAns==a+b){
                    inCorrectAns=rand.nextInt(50);

                }
                answers.add(inCorrectAns);
            }
        }
        button0.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
        button1.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(1)));
        button2.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(2)));
        button3.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(3)));
    }

    public void startButton(View view){
        startButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    public void answerFunction(View view){
         int tappedLocation= (int)view.getTag();

        if (tappedLocation==locationOfCorrectAnswer){
            message="Correct!";
            score++;
        }else{
            message="Wrong!";
        }
        answerMessage.setText(message);
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(score) + "/" + Integer.toString(numberOfQuestions));
        numberOfQuestions++;
        generateQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        answerMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageView);
        sumTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sumTextView);
        scoreText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
        timerText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerText);

        generateQuestion();
        new CountDownTimer(30100,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int seconds=(int) millisUntilFinished/1000;
                timerText.setText(Integer.toString(seconds)+"s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                answerMessage.setText("Done");
            }
        }.start();
        button0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans1);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans2);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans3);
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint to the first activity which is crashing?  Did you see how far the code gets?  Did you recently change something to bring this about?  The problem very well could be in your XML.

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` means that the variable you're trying to call the method `setText` on is unassigned. Check that all your variables are being assigned _before_ they are used.

Comment: Also, you say _"because I had altered my code slightly and it stopped working"_... well what did you change? Seriously that should be a pretty big clue and the first place you look.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method generateQuestion(); before assigning value to the buttons: button1, button2 etc. When you do setText on these buttons, it throws a null object reference error. what you can do is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    answerMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageView);
    sumTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sumTextView);
    scoreText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
    timerText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerText);

    button0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans1);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans2);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans3);
    button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans4);

    generateQuestion();
    new CountDownTimer(30100,1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds=(int) millisUntilFinished/1000;
            timerText.setText(Integer.toString(seconds)+"s");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            answerMessage.setText("Done");
        }
    }.start();

}
}
```

That is assign the respective views to the button before calling the generateQuestion()

Comment: I corrected according to @Shubham's suggestion, Now, I get null value from getTag in the answerFunction. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Where are you setting the tag exactly? You need to use setTag() or android:tag (in xml) for getTag() to work

Comment: I added tag in the xml and it worked. Hope this thread will help others in need as well :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: You should mark the question as answered and select the accepted answer, if you think your problem has been solved according to the community rules.